# Looping over one dict. key() in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two methods here that don't seem to want to talk to eachother. I think the way I use my dictionary is slightly wrong and I've probably confused myself a bit:

```
def load(self, msg):

        loadState = {'foo1' { 'FirstObject':1, 'SecondObject':2 }, 'foo2' { 'FirstObject':3, 'SecondObject':4 }}

        foo_objects = loadState.keys()

        for name in foo_objects:
            if name == 'foo1':
                ValueTuple = loadState[foo_objects[0]]
            elif name == 'foo2':
                ValueTuple = loadState[foo_objects[1]]

            self.program.supervisor.setI2c( ValueTuple, foo = name ) #This is where I think it goes wrong
```

Then to store these values, I pass them over to this method which was working previously, put it doesn't like the new method above:

```
def setI2c( self, ValueTuple, foo=None ) :

        for name in foo :
                    object = self.objects[name]
                    for name in ValueTuple :
                        register = reg(name)
                        register.value = regNameValueTuple[name]
```

EDIT: Part where I went wrong:

```
self.program.supervisor.setI2c( ValueTuple, foo = [name] )
```

Comment: You'll need to show the signature of the other method too. When looping over a dictionary, you already get each key, then use that key **directly** to look up a value. Your values are dictionaries not tuples.

Comment: In `setI2c` you don't make use of `object`.

Comment: done, shown signature (I think)

Comment: why is there not a colon between 'foo1' and it's dict value and 'foo2' and it's dict value?

Comment: probably because the array is a lot bigger than the one given so I typed out a manual one to show an example... Keen eyes!

Comment: That object is used elsewhere in the code but it's so long that I just copied and pasted two chunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `load` message can be simplified to:

```
def load(self, msg):    
    loadState = {'foo1' { 'FirstObject':1, 'SecondObject':2 }, 'foo2' { 'FirstObject':3, 'SecondObject':4 }}

    for name, value in foo_objects.iteritems():    
        self.program.supervisor.setI2c(value, foo=name)
```

Here, `foo` is a *string*, one of the keys in `loadState`.

You then loop over `foo` in `setI2c`, where `foo` is still as string. That means you are iterating over the individual characters:

```
>>> foo = 'foo1'
>>> for name in foo:
...     print name
...
f
o
o
1
```

You don't need that loop at all, you most likely wanted this:

```
def setI2c(self, value_dict, foo=None):
    object = self.objects[foo]
    for name in value_dict:
        register = reg(name)
        register.value = regNameValueTuple[name]
```

but you don't actually use `object` anywhere in your code, so that line could be removed altogether.

If `setI2c()` always expects `foo` to be a list of names, then you should pass in a list in `load`:

```
self.program.supervisor.setI2c(value, foo=[name])
```

Comment: That's certainly given me food for thought =)

Comment: It doesn't always expect a name, so above that I have an if statement whereby if no name is given, it does something else

Comment: That iter doesn't work, it won't set the i2c registers, yet my old loop works albeit with [name] added

Comment: It's *not clear* what your code was trying to achieve; all I can do is try to give you more insight into what could be improved based on my understanding.

Comment: Haha sorry about that, though what you gave me can be adapted, thanks very much for your clear explanations =)